# Subject line AmpScript is not populating in Tracking Send

Tags: marketing-cloud

Using the AMP Script. However, the email subject line did not populate in tracking sends.

It is resolved and I achieved this by using - %%=TreatAsContent( )=%%

Thanks for all the suggestions in Trailhead and here.

Comment: This has already been answered for you here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007BHGBmSAP - no need to post it in multiple communities once you have been provided with an answer

Answer (score 2):

This is the excepted behavior.

AMPscript allows you to personalize email content including subject lines for each subscriber, that’s why there is no one correct value that would be visible in tracking. You could have 1000 different subject lines for 1000 different subscribers. That’s why it’s showing the AMPscript string that was used, not the rendered subject.